# Actual sequential writing speed to USB 3.1 SSD far below benchmark data

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ssd, performance

I have a single 5.5GB file on a slow internal SATA-3 magnetic HDD. Windows 10 claims that disk is only "1%" fragmented. The sequential read performance is around 95 MB per second according to crystal disk mark. I made sure there are no other processes running that could interfere.
I want to copy that file to my NTFS formatted ADATA external USB 3.1 SSD. It's connected directly to my USB 3.1 type C connector on the main board using a very high quality brand name cable. The sequential write speed measures more than 500 MB/s.

Now I'd expect at least 50-70MB/s because the conditions are near perfect and the benchmarks show what is possible. Instead I'm getting only 30-45 which is less than half of what the benchmark achieves. Are there any bottlenecks I may have overlooked?

Comment: USB 3.1 can mean one of two things, USB 3.1 Gen 1 which has a transfer speeds of 5 Gbps or USB 3.1 Gen 2 which has a transfer speeds of 10 Gbps.  Which one is your SSD?

Comment: You are overlooking Windows. Try copying using the free [FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/en/), which can achieve true hardware speed.